# Please uncomment the "agree with flag" button in the 10k flag tools!

Tags: feature-request, 10k-tools, flag-queue

9 times out of 10 when reviewing flags you agree with the original flag. However, you've still got to click "flag or disagree", choose the flag reason and then click "ok". Sure, it doesn't seem *too* bad, but when the flag queue holds 425 items like it does now, the time adds up...

My *original* request was to *add* "agree" and "disagree" buttons to each post, but it seems the "agree" button is already there, albeit commented out ;):

[image]

Would it be possible to;

1. Uncomment the "agree with flag" button so we can use it ;)
2. Add a "disagree" button as well

Then it'd look something like this;

[image]

Comment: The button might be there, but I could not find an event attached to it. So it could be that it is not implemented.

Comment: @Bobby: Yeah I tried that myself as well... "uncomment it so we can use it" wasn't meant to be taken *that* literally :).

Comment: @Bobby, I'm not too fluent in C#, but wouldn't commenting an existing button also make the event handlers no longer being exposed? So, it still *could* be a matter of uncommenting, on the server side that is.

Comment: One obvious problem with putting agree and disagree right next to each other: misclicks. Especially since you can't take back your flags, no matter what.

Comment: It won't appear as an HTML comment in the next build...

Comment: @NickCraver: Hahahaha, I get the feeling it still won't be [meta-tag:status-completed] though, right? :P

Comment: @Matt - "we fixed the glitch"